# Test suffers some failures in IntelliJ after pushing my snapshot to GitHub

Tags: selenium, github, intellij-idea

Why is it that when I push my selenium Java snapshot from my local machine to Github, the project folder becomes sort of corrupt and my test suffers one or two failures in IntelliJ?

Comment: Please provide more details. Did you [share IDE project files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839)?

Comment: Hi, I'm quite new at test automation and only started using Git 2 weeks ago. What I did was go to my IDEA project folder on my local machine and that's where I pushed it from using CMD, windows 10. I had to initialize the folder with git init and before going through to push it to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing your project from IntelliJ itself. I use this approach always to publish my projects on git.

1. Open the project
2. In the Menu go to VCS > Import Into Version Control
3. Select "Share Project on GitHub"
4. It'll ask you for new repo name and remote name (by default it'll be origin)
5. If needed it'll show you pop-up for github login.